# Trying to compile a file for the MIPSEL architecture

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, mips32

There is a MINI TCPDUMP project (utcpdump) that I found and managed to tweak and compile for my Linux architecture, but I want to use it in my router's firmware.

`utcpdump: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=13b2d0dd22f683d1da83864de5511276afd6ccbe, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped`

I have already tried using some commands like:

`./configure --target=mipsel-linux-gnu`

```
export CC=mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc  
./configure --host=mipsel-linux-gnu --target=mipsel-linux-gnu
```

All of these attempts result in compilation for my VM architecture. Can someone help me?